# Find Duplicates Records and Assign 'Y' and 'N' to Them in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

[I want to Assign 'Y' to the Duplicate Records & 'N' to the Uinque Records, And Display those 'Y' & 'N'
Flags in Another Column Called 'Duplicate', which is Actually Not Present in the Table.
Like Below Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdp7O.png)

I want to Assign 'Y' to the Duplicate Records & 'N' to the Uinque Records, And Display those 'Y' & 'N'
Flags in Another Column Called 'Duplicate', which is Actually Not Present in the Table.
Like Below

```
Source Table:
-------------
Name,Location
Ram,India
Ram,USA
Ram,Japan
Ram,India
Ram,UK

Target Table:(Output I want)
----------------------------
Name,Location,Duplicate
Ram,India,Y
Ram,India,Y
Ram,Japan,N
Ram,UK,N
Ram,USA,N
```

OR

```
Name,Location,Duplicate
Ram,India,N
Ram,India,Y
Ram,Japan,N
Ram,UK,N
Ram,USA,N
```

How to Write a Query in Oracle/SQL Developer.

Comment: Why do the two outputs have two `Ram,India` rows and why does the first have two `N`s but the second has both `N` and `Y`?

Comment: How is this question different to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75123704/i-want-to-assign-y-to-the-duplicate-records-n-to-the-uinque-records-and-d also asked by you?

Comment: It's a Same Question I Post 2 Times because I Want Solution in Both Oracle And Informatica PowerCenter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() OVER() [analytic function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions156.htm#SQLRF06100).
Assuming that the first one of multiplyed records is considered as unique and the second and every possible other is considered as duplicate here is the code:

```sql
WITH    -- Sample data
    tbl (A_NAME, LOC) as
        (
            Select 'Ram', 'India' From Dual Union All
            Select 'Ram', 'USA'   From Dual Union All
            Select 'Ram', 'Japan' From Dual Union All
            Select 'Ram', 'India' From Dual Union All
            Select 'Ram', 'UK'    From Dual
        )

-- S Q L
Select  A_NAME, LOC, 
        Case When ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By A_NAME, LOC Order By A_NAME, LOC) = 1 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END "DUPLICATE"
From    tbl

R e s u l t:
A_NAME LOC   DUPLICATE
------ ----- ---------
Ram    India N         
Ram    India Y         
Ram    Japan N         
Ram    UK    N         
Ram    USA   N
```

OR

```sql
-- S Q L    2
Select  A_NAME, LOC, 
        Case When COUNT(LOC) OVER(Partition By A_NAME, LOC Order By A_NAME, LOC) > 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END "DUPLICATE"
From    tbl

A_NAME LOC   DUPLICATE
------ ----- ---------
Ram    India Y         
Ram    India Y         
Ram    Japan N         
Ram    UK    N         
Ram    USA   N
```

Comment: @ d r it is Dispaly for First India 'N' but I Want 'Y' instead of 'N' is there any way?

Comment: @VivekPatil Yes, change the case expression and analytic function. Just posted the second versioon.....

Comment: @ d r Thanx it is Properly Working now.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to conditionally use `count` analytic function.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (name, location) as
  2    (select 'Ram', 'India' from dual union all
  3     select 'Ram', 'USA'   from dual union all
  4     select 'Ram', 'Japan' from dual union all
  5     select 'Ram', 'India' from dual union all
  6     select 'Ram', 'UK'    from dual
  7    )
```

Query:

```
  8  select
  9    name,
 10    location,
 11    case when count(*) over (partition by name, location) > 1 then 'Y'
 12         else 'N'
 13    end duplicate
 14  from test;

NAM LOCAT D
--- ----- -
Ram India Y
Ram India Y
Ram Japan N
Ram UK    N
Ram USA   N

SQL>
```