# I want to Assign 'Y' to the Duplicate Records and 'N' to the Unque Records, And Display those 'Y' and 'N' Flags in 'Duplicate' Column

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I want to Assign 'Y' to the Duplicate Records and 'N' to the Unique Records, And Display those 'Y' and 'N'
Flags in 'Duplicate' Column.
Like Below

## Source Table:

```
Name,Location
Vivek,India
Vivek,UK
Vivek,India
Vivek,USA
Vivek,Japan

Target Table:
=============

Name,Location,Duplicate
Vivek,India,Y
Vivek,India,Y
Vivek,Japan,N
Vivek,UK,N
Vivek,USA,N

How to Create a Mapping in Informatica Powercenter?
Which Logic I Should use?
[See the Image for More Clarification][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F20A.png
```

Comment: How is this question different to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75120054/find-duplicates-records-and-assign-y-and-n-to-them-in-sql-developer also asked by you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate count grouping by key columns using aggregator. And then join back to original flow based on key columns.

1. use `Sorter` sort the data based on key columns like name and country in your example.
2. use `Aggregator` to calculate count() group by key columns.

```
out_count= count(*)
in_out - key_column
```

3. use `Joiner` to join aggregator data and sorter data based on key columns. Drag out_count and key columns from aggregator to joiner. Drag all columns from sorter. Do a inner join on key columns.
4. use `Expression` and create an out expression. Use out_count column to calculate your duplicate flag.

```
out_Duplicate = iif( out_count>1, 'Y','N')
```

Whole map should look like this

```
SRC -->SRT ---->AGG-->\
        |------------->JNR-->EXP-->TGT
```

Answer (score 0):

There's one more way to solve it without the `Joiner`, which is costly. I'm going to use the Name, Location sample columns from your example.

1. Use the `Sorter` on the Name and Location
2. Add an `Expression` with variable port for each key column called e.g. `v_prev_Name` and `v_prev_Location`.
3. Assign the expressions accordingly:

   1. `v_prev_Name = Name`
   2. `v_prev_Location = Location`
4. Next create another variable `v_is_duplicate` with following expression:

   - `IIF(v_prev_Name = Name and v_prev_Location = Location, 1, 0)`
5. Move `v_is_duplicate` up the list of ports so that it is before `v_prev_Name` and `v_prev_Location` - THIS IS IMPORTANT. The order needs to be:

   - `v_is_duplicate`
   - `v_prev_Name`
   - `v_prev_Location`
6. Add output port `is_duplicate` with expression simply matching `v_is_duplicate`.

Comment: Thanks a Lot but using this Logic Result Display Like Below: - 
Name,Location,Duplicate
Ram,India,'N'
Ram,India,'Y'
Ram,Japan,'N'
Ram,UK,'N'
Ram,US,'N'

And I want Result like Below: - 
Name,Location,Duplicate
Ram,India,'Y'
Ram,India,'Y'
Ram,Japan,'N'
Ram,UK,'N'
Ram,US,'N'

Comment: This is also optimized map process and will work faster than below answer for huge records. First record doesnt have a previous row so this can be an issue for first row.

Comment: @Koushik Roy Can we Give Some Condition for First Record v_Previous_Row so that this Issue is Resolve?

Comment: Have you tested it? There should be no issue for the first row - it should result in '0' as for  'not a duplicate' as v_prev_Name has not yet been set and will therefore not be equal to input port Name. Give it a try!

Comment: @Maciejg thats what OP doesnt want. OP wants first row to be 1(duplicate=Y). @ OP , its going to be difficult but you can do it. You have to sort the result again but in opposite order(desc), and then compare again to capture first row is duplicate or not.

Comment: Ah, missed it. This is just a matter of sorting then, according to your needs. Thanks @KoushikRoy!

Comment: @Koushik Roy I Don't Understand Can you Briefly Explain?

Comment: that will be a longer answer but here is a summary. Like @Maciejg mentioned, you use sorter > expression... You need to use another set of sorter and expression. Second sorter will sort opposite order than first sorter. Expression will compare exactly same as 
maceij mentioned. Whole map will be like SRT_ASC>EXP>SRT_DESC>EXP > TGT